# Ubuntu Display Resolution Issue

Tags: display, resolution

I just did a clean install of the 64-bit version of Ubuntu 12.10 on a Dell Inspiron 660 and I'm having trouble with my display setup. The PC has an Ivy Bridge i5 with integrated graphics, and the drivers are recognized and seem to be installed correctly.

The problem is I'm stuck with my resolution set to 1024x768 or 800x600 even though I'm on a 16:9 widescreen monitor. Ubuntu also cannot identify the display. I browsed some posts for various older Ubuntu versions for display issues and tinkered a little with xrandr and tried to force the display to a proper 1440x900 resolution, but couldn't get anything to work (I'm a first time linux user so I probably didn't accomplish much).

Anyone have a similar issue or a recommendation on how to get my display set up correctly? I'm hooked to my monitor by VGA, and the monitor also has a DVI input, while the PC has VGA and HDMI out. I'm debating getting an HDMI to DVI cable to see if using digital input fixes anything.

Comment: The cable shouldn't make a difference.  Have you tried deleting your /etc/X11/xorg.conf and letting it be generated on next start?

Answer (score 1):

Try this blog on [fixing monitor resolution with xrandr](http://newtoubuntu.wordpress.com/2010/07/17/ubuntu-10-04-fixing-the-monitor-resolution-with-xrandr/). I hope this can fix it .

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.